# Ethernet chip for Raspberry pi Compute Module 3+?

Tags: ethernet, compute-module-3

I am designing a base board PCB for CM3+. 
According to the datasheet the processor used is **BCM2837B0** which is the same as Raspberry pi 3B+
LAN7515 chip is used in raspberry pi 3b+ which is 1000 base ethernet
But LAN7515 is not for sale anywhere also cannot find the datasheet
Now I can use LAN7500 which is 1000 base but doesn't have USB downstream or LAN9512 which is only 100 base.

Do I have any option which is 1000 base and has usb downstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked for a similar chip, and actually got in touch with Microchip - the sales rep said they didn't even know about the `LAN7515`. It must be a special IC made for the Raspberry Pi Foundation - certainly their volumes are high enough to justify this. As far as I'm aware, there isn't a GBE + USB hub single IC available. Practically, however, I've found using a `USB251x` + `LAN7500` is cheaper and much easier to route on the PCB than using the `LAN951x` ICs.

Comment: I'm doing the same as punyanagari. I'm chosing the chips now, but I don't need the gigabit functionality. What's hard about the LAN951x IC's that you prefer two chips over one (cost is not the issue for me here) ?

Comment: @lode There's nothing wrong with the `LAN951x` chips, but the routing is a bit nasty. Have a look at the pin out - with the downstream USB ports at the top, going clockwise you then have the osc input, then the upstream USB port, then the RX/TX ethernet pairs. This means you probably have to route the diff pairs on both sides of the board to get a reasonable layout. I prefer to run the diff pairs on a single side, unless I'm really space constrained - no ref plane crossings etc.

Comment: I'm a warned man :)

Comment: Hi both which GPIO did you use for RESET OF LAN chip? How did you configure it in the dtb?

Comment: @punyanagari Suboptimally, I just used an RC (10 K, 10 n) on the reset pin. For production, something more robust would be good...

Comment: @awjlogan thanks for your input. Did you have to use EEPROM for your compute module setup?

Comment: @punyanagari No, it was just a personal board, so didn't bother with the EEPROM for it. As I recall, I think I left the pads on the board,.just left it unpopulated.

Comment: Did you have to modify the device tree or anything or did the LAN chip work out of box with Compute module?

Comment: @punyanagari Works out the box (assuming you've connected everything correctly!)